# Do direct methods preserve the non-zero pattern of the system matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I am trying to analyse and compare various direct and iterative solvers for linear systems of equation. 
The following MatLab code helps to check pattern of the system matrix:
A = bucky + 4*eye(60);
[L,U] = lu(A);
figure(1); clf; spy(A); title('A');
figure(2); clf;
subplot(1,2,1); spy(L); title('L');
subplot(1,2,2); spy(U); title('U');
And the result that I get is:

How can I interpret these plots? Also Do these matrices preserve any particular structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want to know is: what factors control the sparsity pattern of the LU factors in a sparse direct factorization.

This is actually a deep and important question in numerical linear algebra, and different methods for reordering the degrees of freedom give different results.

Basically, if the matrix is $N$-by-$N$, and

- you use a good method
- the sparsity pattern of the matrix is "morally equivalent" to local interactions between points in a $d$-dimensional space,

then the number of nonzeros created in the factors is proportional to 
$$(N^{(d-1)/d})^2 \log N.$$ 
I.e., the sparse factorization requires the same memory (up to a log factor) as as a dense factorization of a matrix whose degrees of freedom live in a space one dimension lower.

The reason is that the best methods (including the method Matlab uses, [SuperLU](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~xiaoye/SuperLU/)) are based on the idea of nested dissection. The degrees of freedom are partitioned into three groups such that two of the groups do not interact with each other; they only interact with the third group, called the "separator front". Then these groups are recursively subdivided into three groups in the same way, and so on until the groups are very small. When you do LU with this ordering, the submatrices associated with the separator fronts get filled in and become dense.